# Is "raise a specter of doubt" an incorrect use of the idiom?

Tags: idioms, idioms-in-context

Warning, major spoilers for "Gone Girl" by David Fincher. First a little bit of background/reminder.

> This is said when one of the characters in the picture prepares to stage a murder (her husband being the murderer who is supposed to be accused of killing her). The plot betrays this much later in the movie. She describes as a narrator what you need to do to prepare perfectly an appearance of a crime. She says it while knocking furniture around the house and creating false evidence by leaving her blood everywhere in the house.

This is a sentence I've got troubles with.

> Meticulously stage a crime scene, with just enough mistakes to raise a specter of **doubt**.

The Free Dictionary defines [raise the specter of (something)](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/raise+the+specter+of+(something)) as

> To make people aware of or worry about **something unpleasant, dreadful, or terrifying.**
> *The sudden dip in stock prices has raised the specter of another global recession with some investors.*
> *Throughout the Cold War, politicians raised the specter of Communism and the Iron Curtain over anything they thought to be "un-American."*

But doubt is not **something unpleasant, dreadful, or terrifying.**
This sentence would make perfect sense to me if it went: "Meticulously stage a crime scene, with just enough mistakes to raise a specter of a murder"

What am I not getting ?

Comment: You are not getting that the author of the sentence is a bad writer, or else the scriptwriters intended the narrator to speak in a sloppy fashion. The 'raise the spectre ("specter")' expression has been altered and wrongly used. We raise **the** spectre of **something that might happen**, and it is always something bad.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey No worries. It's always tricky when multiple folks are messing with a post at the same time.

Comment: @Static One advantage to using the spoiler formatting is that [search won't index the text in the spoiler block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245656/273494), so people can't accidentally have the story spoiled if a search returns your answer. Just use `>! ` in front of the text.

Comment: @ColleenV - I felt that this Q had far too many words, and the style was a little "Hi, folks!" for my liking. That's what my edit was aimed at.

Comment: I don't think the sentence is that bad.  It's a bit of an odd usage of *specter of a doubt*, which is usually used in a negative sense - "there is not a specter of a doubt that President Buttle will be re-elected" - but it's perfectly understandable: it raises a faint ghost of a doubt.